# Automating bullet lists in quarto with Word output

Tags: r, quarto

I want to make an automated bullet list in Quarto. The input would be `items<-c("item1", "item2", "item3")`. The output should be

items

- item1
- item2
- item3

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a small custom function and chunk option `results='asis'`you could do:

````
---
title: "Bullet List"
format: docx
---

```{r}
bullet_list <- function(...) {
  cat(paste0("- ", c(...), collapse = "\n"))
  cat("\n")
}
```

```{r results="asis"}
bullet_list(paste("Item", 1:3))
```

Blah blah

```{r results="asis"}
bullet_list("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
```

Blah blah
````

[image]